# odoo docker multiple instances

Tags: docker, odoo

Running multiple ODOO instances with docker works, but the instance which in not linked to the port 8069 doesn't load the CSS definitions:

```
$ docker run -p 8075:8069 --name odoo2 --link db:db -t odoo
```

e.g. 'http://address.of.server:8075'

Which Setting is missing?

Comment: Are both instances connected to the same DB?  If so check my comment below the answer from PyGuy.

Answer (score 1):

When using nonstandard ports, you should perform some additional configuration.

https://docs.docker.com/samples/library/odoo/

Please note that for plain use of mails and reports functionalities, when the host and container ports differ (e.g. 8070 and 8069), one has to set, in Odoo, Settings->Parameters->System Parameters (requires technical features), web.base.url to the container port (e.g. 127.0.0.1:8069).

Comment: But what then, is the point of `web.base.url`?  If it doesn't break anything else to set it to `127.0.0.1:8069` then why not just have a data XML file always set it to that?

Comment: NOTE: that when you log in as admin, [that is supposed to be overwritten](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/system-parameters-web-base-url-143575) automatically, unless you add `web.base.url.freeze` = `True`